Question about the induced two-norm of pseudo-inverse matrix
Given a full row rank matrix $A\in R^{m\times n}$, where $n>m$. Let $A^+$ be the pesudo-inverse matrix of $A$ and $a_{ij}$ be the element of this matrix, where $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$
When I perform simulations and randomly generate matrices, I have observed that the inducced-two norm $\|A^+\|_2$ decreases as I add more columns and non-zero elements to matrix $A$. This leads me to wonder if this observation is merely a coincidence or if there is a mathematical explanation behind it. I would appreciate it if someone could kindly explain why the induced two-norm $\|A^+\|_2$ tends to decrease in this scenario.

A random ‘fat’ matrix tends to have full row rank. In fact, if the elements of $A$ are sampled from a continuous distribution, the probability of generating a matrix of full row rank is $1$. Now, when $A$ has full row rank, we have
$$
\|A^+\|_2=\sigma_\min(A)^{-1}=\lambda_\min(AA^T)^{-1/2}.
$$
If you augment a column $v$ to $A$, the augmented matrix $B=\pmatrix{A&v}$ also has full row rank. Since $BB^T=AA^T+vv^T\succeq AA^T\succ 0$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering, we obtain $\lambda_\min(BB^T)\ge\lambda_\min(AA^T)>0$. Therefore
$$
\|B^+\|_2=\lambda_\min(BB^T)^{-1/2}\le\lambda_\min(AA^T)^{-1/2}=\|A^+\|_2.
$$

(Below is the old answer invalidated by the OP’s edit to the question.)
The conventional name of your so-called Euclidean norm of a matrix is Frobenius norm. Its standard notation is $\|\cdot\|_F$, not $\|\cdot\|_2$. The latter notation often refers to the induced $2$-norm of a matrix (a.k.a. spectral norm, which is the largest singular value of the matrix) and sometimes also to the Schatten $2$-norm. The formula $\|X\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_i\sum_jx_{ij}^2}$ can be more succinctly be written as $\|X\|_F=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(XX^T)}$.
The behaviour of Frobenius norm when adding a column is easy to explain. A random ‘fat’ matrix tends to have full row rank. In fact, if the elements of $A$ are sampled from a continuous distribution, the probability of generating a matrix of full row rank is $1$. Now, when $A$ has full row rank, we have $\|A^+\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}\big((AA^T)^{-1}\big)$. This can be easily proved by using singular value decomposition. Alternatively, as $A$ has full row rank, $A^+$ is identical to $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$. Therefore
$$
\|A^+\|_F^2
=\operatorname{tr}\big(A^+(A^+)^T\big)
=\operatorname{tr}\big(A^T(AA^T)^{-2}A\big)
=\operatorname{tr}\big(AA^T(AA^T)^{-2}\big)
=\operatorname{tr}\big((AA^T)^{-1}\big).
$$
If you augment a column $v$ to $A$ to form $B=\pmatrix{A&v}$, we have $BB^T=AA^T+vv^T\succeq AA^T\succ 0$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering. Therefore $(BB^T)^{-1}=(AA^T+vv^T)^{-1}\preceq (AA^T)^{-1}$. In turn, $\|B^+\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}\big((BB^T)^{-1}\big)\le\operatorname{tr}\big((AA^T)^{-1}\big)=\|A^+\|_F^2$.

Thank you for pointing that out and for your response. I indeed confused the definitions of the Frobenius norm and the 2-norm. What I am interested in here is the decrease in the induced 2-norm.
